# Spring security ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy issue

Tags: session, authentication, spring-security, concurrency, controls

We are using spring security (org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy) to control the number of logins allowed per user. 
Here is the complete configuration:

core-security-context.xml

```
<bean id="sessionRegistry"
        class="org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl" />

    <bean id="sessionStrategy"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy">
        <constructor-arg name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry" />
        <property name="maximumSessions"
            value="${core.web.config.sessionStrategy.maximumSessions.value}" />
        <property name="exceptionIfMaximumExceeded" value="true" />
    </bean>
```

Web.xml

```
<listener>
    <listener -class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher
        </listener-class>
</listener>
```

Value of core.web.config.sessionStrategy.maximumSessions.value is set to 10. 
As per my understanding, this means that one user can have 10 different login sessions. When that user to tries to login at 11th place simultaneously, he should not be allowed to.

But in our case, the user is able to successfully login 5 times simultaneously, but when we tries to login from 6th place, we get below exception:

```
Authentication request failed: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionAuthenticationException: ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy.exceededAllowed
```

Has anyone faced similar issue? It is very difficult to debug this because this is only happening in production environment. QA, UAT and other environment works fine. One big difference between Prod and other environment is that in prod there are multiple application servers (4 in our case), where as QA and UAT have only 1 server. Could that be the cause or it is something else.

While researching about this, I noticed that ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy class is now deprecated. Instead it says to use ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy. Any idea why this class was depcrecated? Could it be due to a bug in that class?

```
public class UserInfo implements org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails {

@Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        UserInfo other = (UserInfo) obj;
        if (userEntityId == null) {
            if (other.userEntityId != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!userEntityId.equals(other.userEntityId))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Note that the control is on the `Principal` of the authenticated user. In Spring Security this is the implementation of [`UserDetails`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.7.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetails.html) that you are using. If you are using a custom `UserDetails` (maybe a custom `UserDetailsService`?) then its `equals` method is very important.

Comment: Thanks @BoristheSpider for your comment. Yes, we are using custom UserDetailsService:  "public class UserDetailService implements org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService". This class only has 1 method - loadUserByUsername(String userName) in which we are getting userInfo object from database based on userName. There is no overriding of equals method in this class. Are you suggesting that we need to override the equals method in UserDetailsServiceImpl class?

Comment: Not on the _service_ but on the bean you return from the service. Is that a custom implementation of [`UserDetails`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.2.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetails.html)?

Comment: Re: clustering. How are you clustering sessions? Spring uses the backing server's sessions, and keeps a `Map` of active sessions using `HttpSessionEventPublisher` to detect when new sessions are created. If you are using a naive approach to clustering, it might be that an event is fired for **each** server creating a session...

Comment: Re deprecation. This is simply a rearrangement of internal Spring structures to decouple different types of session authentication - see [the migration guide for details](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/migrate/current/3-to-4/html5/migrate-3-to-4-xml.html#m3to4-deprecations-web-cscs).

Comment: Thanks again @BoristheSpider. Sorry I misunderstood your statement. The bean that is getting returned from service is custom UserInfo object that implements org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails  . The equals method in UserInfo class is overridden, but that looks OK to me. Please see that above in question. Just edited that

Comment: Yes, that indeed looks fine, assuming the business logic is consistent with how your users are structured. I suspect the problem is much more painful then - possibly related to the cluster creating a session on each member and the session creation event being fired multiple times.

Comment: Yes @BoristheSpider, my suspect also is that it could be due to cluster. Tried couple of things today and will get the result tomorrow. Fingers crossed :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm the property value for `core.web.config.sessionStrategy.maximumSessions.value` in the Prod environment? It may be different between Prod and other environments.

Comment: Thanks. Yes we validated those values and they are what they should be in both prod and non-prod environments. Any idea on my comment on "Multiple server"? Not sure how this whole thing will work in case of clustered environment.

Comment: Is the prod environment configured for sticky sessions? Are you using Spring Session to centralize sessions to an external store or simply using the underlying server session store?

Comment: Also, please ensure your configuration is setup as per [reference doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.9.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#concurrent-sessions) .Your current configuration "core-security-context.xml" may be missing some of the core components.

Comment: I am not sure at this point about the sticky session. Have asked the deployment team to check on that. Actually got involved in this project couple of days back only and this is the first assignment I got :). We are not using any external store, its just using an underlying server session store.

Comment: To help with troubleshooting, you can enable _debug_ or _trace_ level logging for logger `org.springframework.security.core.session`. The `SessionRegistryImpl` will log extra info that may be helpful.